# How convert Time and Date

Tags: r, datetime, time

I have one question. How to convert that format `20110711201023` of date and time, to the number of hours. This is output of software which I use to image analysis, and I can’t change it.  It is very important to define starting Date and Time.
Format: 2011 year, 07 month, 11 day, 20 hour, 10 minute, 23 second.
Example:

```
Starting Data and Time - 20110709201023,
First Data and Time - 20110711214020
Result = 49,5h.
```

I have 10000 data in this format so I don't want to do this manually.
I will be very gratefully for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best is to first make it a real R time object using `strptime`:

```
time_obj = strptime("20110711201023", format = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
```

If you do this with both the start and the end date, you can simply say:

```
end_time - start_time
```

to get the difference in seconds, which can easily be converted to number of hours. To convert a whole list of these time strings, simply do:

```
time_vector = strptime(dat$time_string, format = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
```

where `dat` is the data.frame with the data, and `time_string` the column containing the time strings. Note that strptime works also on a vector (it is vectorized). You can also make the new time vector part of dat:

```
dat$time = strptime(dat$time_string, format = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
```

or more elegantly (at least if you hate `$` as much as me :)):

```
dat = within(dat, { time = strptime(dat$time_string, format = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S") })
```

Comment: In order to avoid nasty surprises, I recommend that you always specify the time zone when doing date-time conversions. `strptime` has an argument `tz` for that, e.g., you could use `strptime("20110711201023", format = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S",tz="GMT")`.